# Need a better approach to handle "if the query was a success or not" it gives error, but the code working fine and also generating required result,

Tags: php, database, mysqli

here is my code, please have a look and suggest me how to handle the error,

it gives error on the following line,

**if($result > 0):**

here i'm trying to see if the query get any value from database so it should be grater than 0,

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['e_mail']) && isset($_POST['password'])):
        $post_email = $_POST['e_mail'];
        $post_password = $_POST['password'];

        $link = new mysqli('localhost','root','','art_db');

        if($link->connect_error)
            die('connection error' . $link->connect_error);

        $sql = "SELECT e_mail, password FROM signup WHERE e_mail='". $post_email ."' ";

        $result = $link->query($sql);

        if($result > 0):
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
                if($row['e_mail'] == $post_email):
                    echo 'artist-info retrived<br>';
                else:
                    echo 'Unable get artist-info';
                endif;

            echo 'Login Successful. Click <a href="artist-info.php">here</a> to Display Artist Records.';

        else:
            echo 'Unable to Login';
        endif;

        $link->close();

    die();
    endif;  
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>LogIn Form</title>
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="form.css">-->
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column-one-half">
            <div class=form-container class="sign-up-form" >
                <h2>LogIn form</h2>
                <form action="login-form.php" method="post">
                    <input type="text" class="inputs" name="e_mail" placeholder="example@email.com" />
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="password" class="inputs" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="Submit" value="LogIn" class="btn" name="Login" id="login-btn" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check `$result->num_rows` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `if( isset( $result ) )` or `if( isset( $result )` && `($result > 0) )` instead of   `if($result > 0):` and let me know if you are getting error.

Comment: thanks for the help. I tried both,   if( isset( $result ) ) it works fine.

Comment: but can you tell me why we get this error ?,
Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int in C:\wamp\www\php\wstl\forms\login-form.php on line 15

Comment: @OmarAbbas if it will be undefined when `if` is executing what it will do ?

Comment: if you are asking " $result " is undefined, then it will not execute the if statement and will directly execute the else part of that if/else statement.

Comment: @OmarAbbas  then why you do not get the else part working ??

Comment: clue : The non-existence of the variable does not equate to false .I think it clears your idea about if .